# Convert order for find ... -exec

Tags: find, rename

I want to rename files and directories. Let's suppose that I want to convert every `ä` to `a`, and I have `Järjestelmä/Säätimet`. So I say something like `find -exec rename 's/ä/a/g'`. Now `find` will convert `Järjestelmä` to `Jarjestelma` and then complain that it did not found `Järjestelmä` anymore.

If I could convert the order of `exec`-commands to run it would solve this. Is it possible? If not, what is the right way to do this?

This is not a big problem, as I can run the command again until it makes no changes. Anyways this irritates me.

Comment: `find -depth` ?

Comment: @Celada, you mean to run `-depth 1`, `-depth 2` etc. until `find` finds nothing?

Comment: @JoriMäntysalo, you are thinking of `-maxdepth`

Comment: @StigHemmer, you are right. My mistake. (But the question is still open, see below.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find`'s `-depth` option, from the man page:

```
-depth Process each directory's contents before the  directory  itself.
          The -delete action also implies -depth.
```

That way it will process `Säätimet` before `Järjestelmä` and will not complain about not being able to descend into `Järjestelmä` because you just renamed it.

To prevent `rename` from handling the whole path use `-execdir` present in a few `find` implementations like BSDs and GNU (which changes to the directory and hands just the final part to the command argument `{}` (with a `./` prefix with some implementations)):

```
mkdir Järjestelmä
touch Järjestelmä/Säätimet
find . -depth -execdir rename 's/ä/a/g' {} \;
find .
```

gives:

```
./Jarjestelma
./Jarjestelma/Saatimet
```

Comment: I still got the error. Can you give an example of a whole command? I tested with `find x -depth -exec rename 's/a/b/g' {} \;` where x is a directory.

Comment: Your perl expression for rename does change the whole path, it should just change the basename. That is of course never going to work.

Comment: Excellent! This should be linked to older questions about renaming files.